# openlayers drawshapes no lines when drawing at mobile(by touch)

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-shapes.html

There's a feature I'm implementing from the example above on mobile, is about draw a box then erase that area, the problem is that when I switch to touch(there's mobile against mobile not touch at Chrome's device toolbar to simulate touch event at phone screen).  There's nothing but two points during the drawing process. And when switch to mobile not touch, there's thick blue lines since the event is differently triggered by click.

The user won't know how to use it since my feature is to draw a box then delete the content inside on the layer,(redraw the layer with everything else in the 'drawend' event listener).

I want to have a box showing up during the touch drawing process, is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by using freehand drawing instead. It works well on mobile devices.

https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/draw-freehand.html